# Running Two classes for infinite for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two classes that both have for loops that go on forever. When creating a super I am unable to get the class Second to run due to class FIrst also looping. Here is some sudo code. I am at a loss of how to execute them both and have to them run at the same time.

```
class First:
    def one(self):
        for test1 in test2:
            # go on forever
            print('here is 2')


class Second:
    def two(self):
        for test3 in test4:
            # go on forever
            print('here is 2')


class SuperNumber(First, Second):
    pass


Foo = SuperNumber()
Foo.one()
Foo.two()
```

Comment: execute each method in separate thread

Comment: Can you please show me.

Comment: what are `test2` and `test4`?

Comment: @AlexD, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site.  There are plenty of on-line resources to show you how to use parallel threads and subprocesses.  Search on those terms, follow the coding examples, etc.  When you hit something you *cannot* do on your own, post again.

Comment: Alternatively, remove the for loop within the functions so they do terminate. Then execute `Foo.one()` and `Foo.two()` within a single for loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you want to do two things at once, you need *concurrency*.  Python has a few options built-in for doing several things at once:

## Using coroutines

This is sometimes called *cooperative multitasking*.  Concurrency is all achieved in the main thread.

```
import asyncio

class First:
    async def one(self):
        while True:
            print('here is 1')
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

class Second:
    async def two(self):
        while True:
            print('here is 2')
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

class SuperNumber(First, Second):
    pass

foo = SuperNumber()
one = foo.one()
two = foo.two()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(one, two))
```

That's similar to carrying on two conversations, with one person on the phone and another person face-to-face, by periodically asking each person to hold on a moment.

## Using threading

This uses multiple threads, but still only one CPU.  It's best suited to situations where we can benefit from the release of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), e.g. IO-bound applications.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor    

class First:
    def one(self):
        while True:
            print('here is 1')

class Second:
    def two(self):
        while True:
            print('here is 2')

class SuperNumber(First, Second):
    pass

foo = SuperNumber()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executor.submit(foo.one)
    executor.submit(foo.two)
```

That's similar to when you're cooking dinner, and you put the water on the stove, and then you chop up some vegetables whilst you're waiting for the water to boil.  You [user] don't have to just sit there and watch the water boil, because that's the stove [kernel] job, so you may as well make yourself useful in the meantime.

## Using multiprocessing

This uses multiple CPUs, and is the only solution here that can achieve true *parallelism*, so this approach is generally the best one for CPU-bound applications.  Notice the code is exactly the same as the threading example, but just using a different executor class.  It has the most overhead; you need a Python interpreter per-process, so it's more expensive to scale it up to multiple tasks.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

class First:
    def one(self):
        while True:
            print('here is 1')

class Second:
    def two(self):
        while True:
            print('here is 2')

class SuperNumber(First, Second):
    pass

foo = SuperNumber()

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executor.submit(foo.one)
    executor.submit(foo.two)
```

That's similar to hiring a kitchen-hand to help you chop up vegetables while you chop up vegetables.  You've got to buy another knife and chopping board, but you should be able to get the potatoes chopped in half the time this way.